# Numerical Integration for Arc Length

Tags: integration, arc-length

I'm seeking to calculate arc length without referring to functions that make use of angle measures or pi. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) description of numerical integration seems like a good way to go, but I am not calculating correctly. I'm pretty sure that I understand what *dx* indicates and from the context I have solved for the *x* in the denominator under the radical using the given solution to gain insight, but I am failing to recognize which value *x* should be when it comes time to work the example with other coordinate values. I suspect I am overlooking something terribly obvious; apologies and thanks.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong if you don't show us your calculation.

Comment: Please post the specific problem you are trying to solve. What function are you trying to integrate? If we don't know, it is impossible to tell you what will work. Please use mathjax and post a complete problem statement.

Comment: As an example, I'm looking to verify that I can correctly calculate the length of an arc of the unit circle defined by the points $$(-{\sqrt 2}/2,  {\sqrt 2}/2) ; ({\sqrt 2}/2,  {\sqrt 2}/2)$$ I believe that $$((1/{\sqrt(1-x^2)})dx$$ will get me the length I am looking for. I am not sure what value to exponentiate to perform this calculation.

Comment: This is precisely the example given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length). What part of that do you need help with?